# Can't access SQL Server 2008 with anything but 'Windows NT Integrated Security'

Tags: sql-server

In Management Studio, if I go 'Security' --> 'Logins' --> 'New Login' --> something simple like username='test' and password='test', I am still unable to use this login - why? Is there something really obvious that I am missing?

If I create 'X.UDL' in windows explorer and use 'Microsoft OLD DB Provider for SQL Server', the only way I can get a list of databases is by using 'Windows NT Integrated Security' - none of my logins work.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Authentication is not enabled by [default](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsecurity/archive/2010/12/03/contained-database-authentication-introduction.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2
```

You will then need to restart SQL Server.

Alternatively you can do this through the GUI. In SSMS right click the instance, choose `properties` then choose "SQL Server and Windows Authentication" on the security page. This will still require a restart.